# maximum DateTime in XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xelement

I am trying to find the maximum DateTime value in my XML.

Here is a sample of the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='http://127.0.0.123/sitemaps/xmltemplate/main-sitemap.xsl'?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
  <url>
    <loc>http://127.0.0.123/?????</loc>
    <lastmod>2018-05-13</lastmod>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>0.1</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://127.0.0.123/?????-????</loc>
    <lastmod>2018-05-26</lastmod>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>0.1</priority>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

And here's the code I'm trying to use:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(FullAddressXML);
var maxId = xdoc.Elements("url").Select(x => new {                
        MaxDateTime = x.Descendants("lastmod").Max(y=>(DateTime)y)
    });
```

When I run this, `maxId` is empty.

Comment: Please could you give more details than "it dosent work"? Does it fail to compile? Does it compile but throw an exception? (And if so, what exception?) Does it not throw an exception, but not give you the answer you expect?

Comment: it compiled complet but maxId was empty

Comment: So please edit that detail into the question. A question which only states "It doesn't work" is never a good question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three problems here:

- You're calling `xdoc.Elements("url")` which will never return any elements, because there are no `url` elements as the direct descendant of the document; you'd want `xdoc.Root.Elements` to find the `url` elements within the root element
- You're providing the *local name* of the elements, but due to namespace defaulting, they're actually in a namespace of `"http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"` which you aren't specifying, so it won't find any elements
- You're finding a *sequence* of maximum `DateTime` values, one per `url` element, which almost certainly isn't what you want to do - you presumably want the maximum across *all* URLs.

Additionally, it's not clear why you're creating a new anonymous type with a single property - that's *usually* not useful.

Here's an example which works for your sample data:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
        XNamespace ns = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9";
        var max = doc.Root
            .Elements(ns + "url")
            .Max(url => (DateTime) url.Element(ns + "lastmod"));
        Console.WriteLine(max);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if there will never be any other `lastmod` elements, you could just use `Descendants` on the document itself:

```
var max = doc.Descendants(ns + "lastmod").Max(x => (DateTime) x);
```